# custom cell resizing with textView

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I have tableView with custom cells in it(cells with textView), and I want to resize some of the cells in it depending upon text size. I am doing this with the following code snippet:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    //Load text in NSString which you want in Cell's LabelText.

    NSString *cellText;

    cell.Text = someData

    //define font for Labeltext...
    UIFont *cellFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Georgia" size:19.0];

    CGSize constraintSize = CGSizeMake(330.0f, MAXFLOAT);

    CGSize labelSize_val = [cellText sizeWithFont:cellFont constrainedToSize:constraintSize lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];

    return labelSize_val.height + 20;
}
```

This code works ok in some cases (red square - space of cell):

[image]

But with bigger text it doesn't work properly (making bigger cells with empty space):

[image]

Any ideas how to solve this issue?

Comment: is this `[UIFont fontWithName:@"Georgia" size:19.0];` exactly the font you are using to display? if this is smaller than the real font it will be calculating the height much bigger

Comment: yes, this is exactly font that i'm using to display text in cell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all here u have to Override the height for row At Indexpath and calculate the your string by the function"

```
  - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath   *)indexPath{

     NSString *cellText;
   cellTextHeight = [self heightOfCellForText:cellText];
     return cellTextHeight+margin;
       }        

  -(CGFloat)heightOfCellForText:(NSString *)yourString
      {


             CGRect r = [yourString boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(100.0, 0)
                              options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                   attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont  fontWithName:@"Arial" size:15]}  context:nil];
            CGSize size=r.size;
            CGFloat height=size.height;
            return height;
         }
```

I hope this code is help flu.

Answer (score 0):

I've been used this and works fine for me.

```
 if (SYSTEM_VERSION_LESS_THAN(@"7.0")) {
             // code here for iOS 5.0,6.0 and so on
          CGSize fontSize = [text sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:17]];
           size = fontSize;
          }
           else {
                    // code here for iOS 7.0
                    NSDictionary *attributesDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                                          [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:17], NSFontAttributeName,
                                                          nil];

                    CGRect fontSizeFor7 = [text boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(571, 500)
                                                             options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                                          attributes:attributesDictionary
                                                             context:nil];
                    size = fontSizeFor7.size;
                }
                return size.height +20 ;
```